# perforce depot converted to streams; can't delete old files from non-stream client

Tags: perforce

I have a depot that was initially set up as a non-stream depot. We added some files while sorting out folder structure. The depot was subsequently converted to a streams depot, and I want to remove the old files.

Unfortunately those original files do not appear under any stream, so I can't delete them from a stream-based client.

I do have a non-stream client left from initial testing, and I can open the offending files for delete, but I can't submit them:

> //depot/myworkspace/main/foo.txt - warning: cannot submit from non-stream client

Is there any client-side way to delete the files? (Note that I am not an administrator on the server -- contacting the admin will be my next step.)

Comment: Why do you need to delete them? Are they interfering with other work or causing a problem?

Comment: The files aren't causing a specific problem, but they are visual clutter that may confuse users of the depot.

Comment: The most straightforward way I can think of is to turn the depot back into a non-streams depot, delete the files, and then turn it back to streams, but that will certainly require help from your admin.

Comment: And cooperation from all the users, or do it during maintenance hours. Good suggestion, thanks Bryan.